# Does dependency imply an equation?

Tags: regression, random-variable, cumulative-distribution-function, independence

On regression, we usually think of dependency in terms of an equation relation between variables. For instance, we think that $Y$ "depends" on $X$ If

$$E[Y|X] = g(X) + \epsilon \quad \mbox{or} \quad Var(Y|X) = \sigma^2h(X) \quad.$$

That is, $X$ brings valuable information for predicting the conditional mean, or variance, or other quantity you wish to analyze.

However, random variables independence is defined operationally in terms of probability. Is it possible that two variables are dependent but there is no equational link between them? If so, would its information still be relevant in a regression?

Comment: One wonders what distinction you intend by "equational link."  As an example, consider a situation where a collection of ordered pairs $(x,y)$ is believed to lie on some circle in the plane but each is measured as $(X,Y)$ with independent random error.  Although one *could* attempt to model this in the regression form $Y = f(X,\varepsilon),$ for this problem that would be unnatural, arbitrary, and difficult.  Instead, one would seek parameters for which $(\alpha X-\xi)^2+(\beta Y-\eta)^2-1$ is close to zero. Would that be an "equational link" or not?

Comment: @whuber Indeed, the term "equational link" is loosely used to express isolate $Y$ as a function of $X$ and other terms, I will fix it. In your example, I would say yes because, depending on how you express the random errors, we can probably describe $Y$ in terms of $X$. Moreover, you provided a way to parametrized the problem (and possibly how to fit the parameters). But did you not come up with this formulation because you already know how to parametrize a circle? That is, you already know how $X$ and $Y$ are possibly related?

Comment: In my example you *cannot* describe $Y$ in terms of $X:$ that's the point.

Comment: @whuber Yes, I agree now. I was thinking on the implicit function theorem, but that does not solve the problem. However, at the risk of being vague again, I "extend" the question: if $X$ and $Y$ are dependent, can I find $g$ such that $g(Y, X, \epsilon) = 0$?

Comment: I don't think that's a useful question to ask.  Implicitly, $\epsilon$ must be independent of $(X,Y)$ and the only solution is the constant function $g=0.$  When $X$ and $Y$ are dependent, your task is to infer useful properties of its joint distribution function.  *Which* properties you focus on will depend on your application.  In a regression application, for instance, $X$ and $Y$ have different meanings; they are treated asymmetrically; and one estimates properties of the distribution of $Y$ conditional on $X$ (many times, does not even view $X$ as a random variable).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For simplificity's sake, consider both $X$ and $Y$ to be unidimensional random variables. Assume that $X$ and $Y$ are dependent and denote by $F_{Y|X}(y|x)$ the conditional cdf of $Y$ given $X=x$. Then the representation
$$Y=F^{-}_{Y|X}(\varepsilon|X)\qquad\qquad \varepsilon\sim\mathcal U(0,1)$$
is a [generic and generative representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) of $Y$ through an equation (when $F^{-}_{Y|X}$ is the generalised inverse of $F_{Y|X}$).

Comment: I like the idea shown here, it is aligned with what I had in mind. However, I find @whuber example relevant. What would happen in that case? Would $F_{Y|X}^{-}$ return a set?

Comment: I think both points are different in that this representation assumes the full conditional cdf of $Y$ gien $X$ is available.